# Administrators cannot edit articles after Joomla update

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, category

After Joomla update to 3.6.2 the user group `Administrator` cannot edit some articles while some articles can be edited. `Super Users` can edit all the articles. I think the issue is with the category . When I select the article category as `Uncategorised` the articles can be edited by the administrators. While when I select other category the problem arises. I checked the category permissions of the user group administrators and all are selected to `Allowed`.

---Updated---
I think my `#__assets` table is broken. I tried rebuilding the categories but it didn't work. The `parent_id` column when changed to super users group id `8` as in the uncategorised the articles worked. However, this doesn't work for subcategories.

Kindly, guide me on this issue and let me know if I am going the right way

Comment: Please update to Joomla 3.6.4 and try again.

Comment: I have updated but still the problem is there. When the site was updated to 3.6.2 then this permission issue came

Comment: Make sure that ALL caches are emptied!. Browser cache; Joomla caching, and server caching if any (Siteground is famous for that).

Comment: @Mikan already done :) I have found that my assets table is somehow broken for the categories. I rebuilt it but still the same issue. I will update my question with what I have found

Comment: Well then... I would try ACL Manager's famous Fixing Assets command...

Comment: @mikan which command? Can you please elaborate

Comment: ACL Manager | Diagnostics tab, then (Fix Orphan Assets / Add Missing Assets / Fix Assets Issues / Fix Admin Access Conflicts) if any...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using ACL Manager fix assets feature plus few manual steps. The problem was that there were duplicate categories with same name and same alias were created at the time of Joomla update as a child element of the main category plus assets table was broken. Following are the steps which I took:

1. Changed the alias and deleted the unnecessary categories very carefully that were not used.
2. Installed ACL manager and go to **Diagnostic** tab and fix the broken assets.
3. I was facing a problem that assets fixation was stuck in a loop and same items were listed again and again when the **fix asset** button was clicked.
4. Open and re-save the items listed in ACL manager component. They can be articles, categories or modules.

And done. The problem was solved. However, for huge content step (4) will be hectic.

Answer (score 4):

Well then... I would try ACL Manager's famous Fixing Assets command...

ACL Manager | Diagnostics tab, then (Fix Orphan Assets / Add Missing Assets / Fix Assets Issues / Fix Admin Access Conflicts) if any...

Answer (score 3):

We have encountered the exact same issue, and it turned out to be indeed, a corruption in the `#__categories` and in the `#__assets` table where the entries for certain categories pointed to the wrong assets (these categories didn't have asset entries in the `#__assets` table in the first place). Fixing this consists of recreating the asset entry for the category in the `#__assets` table. You can read how we fixed this problem [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/are-you-unable-to-edit-your-joomla-articles-read-this).

What is odd is that this problem only started happening when the client was updated to Joomla 3.6.4 (the client was using Joomla 3.5.1).

Comment: thanks for the answer but in my case following answer helped. And Vote-up for your answer :)